# Find a differential equation satisfying:

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

> The population in a certain country grows at a rate proportional to the population at time $t $, with proportionality constant of $0.03$. Due to political turmoil, people are leaving the country at a constant rate of $6000$ per year. Assume there's no immigration to the country. Let $P=P (t) $ is population time at $t $, the being in years.
>
> Write the differential equation reflecting the situation.
>
> Solve it for $P (t) $ given that at $t=0$ the population is 3 million. Find $P (t)$.

I'm stuck on the DE. I know it should have a $-6000$ but the $1.03$ is throwing me off.

Comment: Generally, populations grow at a rate proportional to the population itself.  That is because, assuming a constant birth rate, the average number of births per child, the increase will be some constant times the current population.   That is, dP/dt= kP.  With a birth rate of 0.03, the new population will be P+ 0.03P= (1.03)P so k= 1.03.   With an additional 6000 leaving you have dP/dt= 1.03P- 6000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the discrete system, $P_{t+1} = P_t + 0.03 P_t - 6000$ $(\star)$, then converting this **very informally** gives

$$P_{t+1} - P_t = 0.03 P_t - 6000$$
so
$$\frac{P_{t+1} - P_t}{\delta t} = \frac{0.03 P_t - 6000}{\delta t}$$
Taking the limit as $\delta t \rightarrow 0$ on the LHS gives
$$P'(t) = \frac{0.03}{\delta t} P(t) - \frac{6000}{\delta t}$$
**Note that** the reason I keep the $\delta t$ on the RHS is because they are *actually "constants"* and will cancel out in the solving process.

---

The more standard way of doing this is to write $P_{t+1} = P(t+\delta t)$ and note that your $0.03$ and $6000$ are actually $0.03 \delta t$ and $6000 \delta t$. Thus  $\frac{P_{t+\delta t} - P_t}{\delta t} = \frac{0.03 \delta t P_t - 6000 \delta t}{\delta t}$. Therefore $$P'(t) = 0.03 P(t) - 6000$$

---

Solving this system with $P(0) = 3000000$, you get 
$$P(t) = 200000 + Ce^{0.03t}$$
or with the given initial condition,
$$P(t) = 200000 + 2800000e^{0.03t}$$

Because of some potential problems with the conversion, I'd sick to the difference equation $(\star)$ for this problem.